# Position font according to its origin

Tags: html, css

**Problem:**

How can text be positioned to the centre based on the width of the text?

**Code:**

The following is my css:

```
#title{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top:5%;
    font-size:70px;
}
```

The following is my HTML:

```
<div id = 'title'>This is my lovely title</div>
```

**Further Details:**

The problem here is that the text "This is my lovely title" **starts** at the centre, but I want it balanced and aligned to the centre. How can I specify the position of the text's origin? Is it possible to use standard CSS to accomplish this?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/wgBrw/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#title{
    text-align: center;
    font-size:70px;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, I've also seen people use margin-left and margin-right:auto to achieve the same effect.

Comment: You can do that to center a div (or a block element in general) inside its parent, but you would still need to center the text in the div. It does not auto-size to the width of the text.

Comment: Sorry for the simple question. Thanks

Comment: I think what @ManidipSengupta mentioned is the same affect as my code